# Using Surface View for camera and others for overlay image

Tags: android, android-layout

im new in android programming..
i have a problem here.

i wanna make an application that draw overlay on top real view from camera.
i use surface view for hold image from camera.

here my XML for my main activity:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/preview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />
        <com.openit.razer.overlayPreview
            android:id="@+id/overlayprev"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        <com.openit.razer.overlayImage
            android:id="@+id/overlayimg"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is my main activity class:
p

```
ublic void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ar);

        overPrev = (overlayPreview)findViewById(R.id.overlayprev);
        overImg = (overlayImage)findViewById(R.id.overlayimg);

        overImg.setZOrderOnTop(true);
        overImg.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);


        preview=(SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.preview);
        previewHolder=preview.getHolder();
        previewHolder.addCallback(surfaceCallback);
        previewHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}
SurfaceHolder.Callback surfaceCallback=new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
          try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(previewHolder);
          }
          catch (Throwable t) {
            Log.e("PreviewDemo-surfaceCallback",
                  "Exception in setPreviewDisplay()", t);
            Toast
              .makeText(ARrazerNav.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
              .show();
          }
        }

        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder,
                                   int format, int width,
                                   int height) {

          Camera.Parameters parameters=camera.getParameters();
          //Camera.Size size=getBestPreviewSize(width, height,
                                             // parameters);
          List<Camera.Size> sizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
          Camera.Size selected = sizes.get(0);
          parameters.setPreviewSize(selected.width, selected.height);
          camera.setParameters(parameters);
          if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
              camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
          }
          else{
              camera.setDisplayOrientation(0);
          }
          //camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
          //camera.setDisplayOrientation(0);
          camera.startPreview();
        }

        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
          // no-op
        }
      };
```

but i got errror

```
FATAL EXCEPTION:main
...
...
...
caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class blablabla
```

could u help me to solve my problems. it was a 3 days im stuck in this problem.

and whats the best method for implementing Camera with SurfaceView and overlay image on top of it?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using a FrameLayout to place views on top of other views. SurfaceView first, then the views you want on top of it.

I actually did this myself, putting an image over a camera preview. I used a FrameLayout with a SurfaceView and an ImageView on top of it. Worked pretty well.

Comment: What error? And on what line? You should update your post with your new XML using the FrameLayout so I can see what you're doing now. Also. Does your custom view inherit from SurfaceView by chance..?