# Calibrated PNG over google map

Tags: android, google-maps, png, tiles, layer

I have a google map activity with trails, pois, proximity alerts, etc. and I would like to put a new PNG map (new layer) over the current google map at the same position (calibrated by latitude and longitude). How could I do that?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Google Maps [Overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/maps/Overlay) functionality. Here is a rough outline for what needs to be done.

```
public class PNGOverlay extends Overlay {
  Bitmap mImage;
  // Allocate once and reuse
  private final Paint mPaint = new Paint();

  PNGOverlay(Bitmap image) {
    mImage=image;

    // Configure paint so image is transparent 
  }

  /**
  * Draw the overlay over the map.
  * 
  * @see com.google.android.maps.Overlay#draw(Canvas, MapView, boolean)
  */
  @Override
  public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapv, boolean shadow) {
    // Use projection to figure out where to draw
    Point center = new Point();
    Projection projection = mapv.getProjection();
    projection.toPixels(new GeoPoint(lat,lon), p);

    // Transform image to fill the correct area
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix;
    // Do stuff

    // Draw the image
    canvas.drawBitmap(mImage, matrix, mPaint);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding both views to a FrameLayout? I would recommend that you make the top one transparent, however.

[Using Surface View for camera and others for overlay image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10841235/using-surface-view-for-camera-and-others-for-overlay-image)

Comment: and what about with the google map functionalities (zoom, markers, etc.)? Everything will be working fine?

Comment: Maybe you should show us the code that you have tried and we can help from there